# How is it possible that a list was given as a parameter to a function that expects a tuple?

Tags: python, syntax, pytorch

I was watching a tutorial on PyTorch and coding along and got stuck on function `torch.randint`
According to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.randint.html#torch.randint):

> torch.randint(low=0, high, size, \*, generator=None, out=None,
> dtype=None, layout=torch.strided, device=None, requires_grad=False) →
> Tensor

here, `size` is :

> size (tuple) – a tuple defining the shape of the output tensor.

The YouTuber wrote

```py
  random_idx = torch.randint(0, len(train_data), size=[1]).item()
```

But `[1]` is not a tuple, it is a list. How is this possible?
I also tested it with a tuple and it worked just fine and every usage of `randint()` i found on the internet provides a tuple for `size`. E.g. `size = (1,2)` or `size = (1,1)`.

I searched the source code for `torch.randint` but could not find it. I searched GitHub, PyTorch docs and even tried to find it in a local PyTorch library.

Comment: It depends on what the code does with the parameter.

Comment: Typing in python is considered a type "hint", as in it's not disallowed to post whatever you want as a parameter. The implementation of the function uses qualities and functionalities that both `tuple` and `list` have so it works interchangably. Try with a `set()` as well!

Comment: @luk2302 Any Ideas on how and where to get the source code for that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that this should be a `tuple` however in practice, the definition of `randint()` is:

```
def randint(low: _int, high: _int, size: _size, ... )
```

Where `_size` is defined as:

```
(type alias) _size: Type[Size] | Type[List[int]] | Type[Tuple[int, ...]]
```

So in practice, the requirement is for the `size` parameter to be of type `Size`, `List` of int or `Tuple` of int, which will pretty much behave the same in this case

**EDIT:**
As stated above, indeed, typing is only an indicative in Python, so if you use any type of variable, there won't be any issue if the function itself doesn't raise an error. For the question of why the function acts accordingly and returns what is expected, this is because of the first part of the answer :)

Comment: Where did you get info about the definition of `_size`? I could not find the location or a file of the source code where these functions are defined.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between a list and a tuple is that you cannot modify a tuple once it has been created. If you want the array to be immutable, you'd want to change it to a tuple yes, but otherwise, all read operations between lists and tuples are identical, so your code will work just fine :).